# Header location input error

Tags: php

I have problems with custom search input that redirects to id:
**mysite/search/$id**.

The thing is that is working, but.. when I'm at this site:
http://**mysite/search/$id** after entering again into input some id it display it as **mysite/search/search**

How can I solve it?

The code I use

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
    header("Location: search/$name");
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="search"> <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="submit"> </form>
```

Comment: Try: `header("Location: http://mysite/search/$id");` Does that do the trick?

Comment: *Why is this code not working?*

Comment: @Rizier123 `$name = $_POST['id']; / $id` ;-) another *unclear*.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yeah I know, isn't it lovely how things work, then *suddenly* stop working? And for no apparent reason; or obvious reason.

Comment: @Rizier123, it doesn't do the trick

Comment: `header("Location: http://www.example.com/search/$name");` using the full http call, and you should be using a conditional statement in all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `$id` defined? It looks like you want

```
 header("Location: search/$name");
```

EDIT:

After seeing your form, you'll want to change your PHP to:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
header("Location: search/" . $name );
```

EDIT:

I have tested this and it works. Your action in the form is what's causing the issue. Change your code to this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    header("Location: /search/$name");
}
?>
<form method="post"> <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="submit"> </form>
```

Comment: Yeah, but with name is same problem, after redirect to page and trying to enter some value to it, it's work's same > redirecting to mysite.com/search/search

Comment: @Conservation I'm going to need your whole form code in order to help you further

Comment: $name = $_POST['name'];
header("Location: search/$name");

<form method="post" action="search">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: @Conservation no wonder it's not working, there is no input with the name of `id`.

Comment: the code looks like on 1st post (edited), when I'm on index page, it redirects me to `./search/example` but when I'm on that `./search/example`
and try to submit value in input it redirects to `./search/search`
Also added `id="name"` to input with hope it will change sth, but still same

Comment: Sorry, but it's still redirecting to `./search/search`

Comment: Almost works :)
It redirects to `/search/search/test` instead of `search/test`

Edit:
Solved, instead of search/$name I used all http call :)

Comment: @Conservation change to `header("Location: /search/$name");`